# How do I retrieve DNS records in Angular or Node

Tags: node.js, angular, dns

I have an App built in Angular 8 with Universal implemented. On the API I have NodeJS with Express. So I would like to point other doains to my website so that users can access a user profile on App from their domain. What I mean is:

1. My domain is mydomain.com
2. otherdomain.com points to mydomain.com.
3. when people visit otherdomain.com, they will be able to access mydomain.com/profiles/otherdomainprofile with URL showing otherdomain.com

**Q1.** How can I achieve this in Angular or with Node. Is there a way to get the DNS records of otherdomain from Angular?

**Q2.** Can I get the source domain, that is otherdomain.com in an Angular App.